# script.sh: 1: docker: not found, jenkins not seeing docker commands

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I faced a problem, I made my simple pipeline: "build" and "compose up". Stage 1 works, but the second doesn't, referring to the fact that the the docker commands inside jenkins are absent. I didn't install Jenkins locally, only run as a container. To sum up,  I've got an error. **docker compose up
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/myPipeline@tmp/durable-8e128f98/script.sh: 1: docker: not found** .
Docker plugin on jenkins doesn't help. docker-compose up doesn't work on Jenkins as well. Please help how to make this work.

```
Docker-compose file
version: '3'
    services:
      jenkins:
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        restart: always
        privileged: true
        user: root
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
          - 50000:50000
        container_name: jenkins
        volumes:
          - /home/ubuntu/jenkins_compose/jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

                


**My pipeline**
    pipeline {
        agent any
        triggers {
            pollSCM '* * * * *'
        }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    sh './gradlew assemble'
                }
            }
            stage('Run Docker Images') {
                steps {
                    sh 'docker compose up'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is docker installed in the environment where you call it? Is it available in PATH?

Comment: @knittl , no, I didn't install docker on Jenkins. How will it install there?